# Why this JS code with jQuery tkey attribute to provide different html strings for different languages doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

I've been building my first html portfolio, and as I'm a translator by trade I thought it would be interesting to provide multilingual support to it. I've searched the web (and Stack Oververflow more specifically) for options, and eventually reached this solution:

lang.js:

```
var langs = ['en', 'pt'];
var langCode = '';
var langJS = null;


var translate = function (jsdata)
{   
    $("[tkey]").each (function (index)
    {
        var strTr = jsdata [$(this).attr ('tkey')];
        $(this).html (strTr);
        console.log('strTr is: '+strTr)
    });
}


langCode = navigator.language.substr (0, 2);
console.log('langCode is: '+langCode)

if (langCode in langs)
    $.getJSON('lang/'+langCode+'.json', translate);
else
    $.getJSON('lang/pt.json', translate);
```

html snippet:

```
<div class="odd" id="SkillsLanguages">
    <h1 tkey="skills-lang"></h1>
</div>
```

the json files are on /lang/

json snippet:

```
{
    "skills-lang" : "Habilidades e Idiomas",
    "proj2" : "GameLibrary App",
    "copyright" : "Copyright by Francisco Llamosas 2018"
}
```

It seems to me it should work, but I'm just starting with webdev and I'm not sure why it doesn't.

The output is just empty text, no strings at all. The CSS stuff renders just fine, the divs, background colors, bootstrap columns, etc, but no text on the webpage

Please note that I'm **NOT** looking for an alternative solution to providing multilingual support for my html website (found a couple of different implementations and I'll work through them in due time), but trying to understand why this particular piece of code doesn't work and what should be fixed so that it does work, if at all possible.

I've tried to provide enough info and context for the issue, but if you need anything else, I'll be glad to provide more code snippets and/or info.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any errors in the console? Have you tried console.logging at different points to see what's actually going on?

Comment: Typographical error. Removing the trailing comma in pt.json worked for me. Allowing trailing commas after the last property in an object literal is a recent addition to JavaScript and invalid in JSON.

Comment: No I didn't. Not sure what to log for, or where on the code to include it. I assume these might be useful for example?

`console.log('langCode is: '+langCode)`
`console.log('strTr is: '+strTr)`

Comment: about the typographical issue with the trailing comma, that's actually a typo on my question write-up. My original json file has multiple entries, and the last one does not have an trailing comma. I'm going to update the question to reflect more properly how my json file is set up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing any trailing comma after the last object/array property in the JSON file, there is a problem with the use of the `in` operator by `if( langCode in langs)`. Language codes are values in the `langs` array, not named properties of it. Instead check if `langCode` is in the array:

```
//   ...

if ($.inArray( langCode, langs) >= 0) {
    $.getJSON('lang/'+langCode+'.json', translate);

}
else {
    $.getJSON('lang/pt.json', translate);
}
```

Comment: thanks for this. It didn't solve the problem though, but perusing the console I figured it out. Turns out I was calling a minified version of jQuery on my html file and changing it to https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js solved the issue.

Comment: I like how `$.inArray` doesn't return a bool like you'd expect. Had to check the docs to make sure you weren't crazy :-)

Comment: @chicobaptista - this fix solves a real problem. Without it my browser's language ("en") is not detected and the portuguese trranslation presented by default.  I tested with jquery 3.2.1 so didn't know you had _another_ problem as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I just tried a altered version at:
https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/138022/

The problem occurs on the line :

```
if (langcode in langs)
```

I removed the line and just called translate(pt) and it works.
Check out the js fiddle and you'll see console.log output.

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out I was calling a slimmed version of jQuery on my html file with `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js` and it does not support the `.getJSON()` method. changing it to `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js` on my html solved the issue. Thanks to all responders though, uncovered other errors on my script.